# How to set base class the values in the derived constructor

Tags: c#

So I got this base class

```
abstract class Item
{
    private int x, y, ataque, defesa, saude, raridade;
    private char appearance;
    private bool pickedUp;
    private readonly Random rng = new Random();

    public Item(Map argMap, int argAtaque, int argDefesa, int argSaude, int argRaridade, char argAppearance)
    {
        bool empty = false;
        while (!empty)
        {
            x = rng.Next(1, argMap.ReLengthX() - 1);
            y = rng.Next(1, argMap.ReLengthY() - 1);
            if (!argMap.CheckTile(y, x)) empty = true;
        }
        pickedUp = false;
        ataque = argAtaque;
        defesa = argDefesa;
        saude = argSaude;
        raridade = argRaridade;
        appearance = argAppearance;
    }
}
```

And I got this derived class

```
class Armadura : Item
{
    public Armadura(Map argMap, int ataque, int defesa, int saude, int raridade, char appearance) : base(argMap, ataque, defesa, saude, raridade, appearance)
    {
        ataque = -1;
        defesa = 2;
        saude = 0;
        raridade = ReRNG().Next(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(argMap.ReLengthY() * 0.02)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(argMap.ReLengthY() * 0.04)));
        appearance = ' ';
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do I get to set the values on :base, using the values that I set on the derived constructor (for example, set the base argAtaque with ataquewwww, therefore, argAtaque being equal to '-1')?
I tried this using a few ways but I didn't get this to work in any way.
I thank you in advance!

Comment: The call to `: base (...)` calls the base constructor that sets the fields in the base class. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: It appears visual studio claims that the values that I define in the derived constructor are never used

Comment: That is correct, you're changing the parameters to the method, *after* they have been passed to the base constructor. If you want to always pass -1 for `ataque` (in this case) you should just change the call to `base` as follows: `: base(argMap, -1, 2, 0, CallToStaticMethodThatProducesRaridade(), ' ');` Also, consider if you really need the parameters *to* that constructor any more, you would most likely only need `argMap`.

Comment: The base constructor will be first executed, then your code in Armadura constructor. So first 'ataque' will be set using the constructor argument, and then set to -1

Comment: Yes I understand this but I can't use fixed values.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want to do. You must explain what you want to do here. What did you mean by `ataque = -1;` ? What do you hope to accomplish by this and the similar lines of code?

Comment: @EpaXapate You probably are looking for an abstract/virtual property, and override that in the derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `: base()` syntax will work for constants and parameters, but not for more complex expressions with side-effects (as you found).

You'll be needing a initialization method on the base class.

```
abstract class Item
{
    ...

    // If you use this constructor, call Setup() afterwards.
    public Item() {}

    // Constructor including a call to Setup()
    public Item(Map argMap, int argAtaque, int argDefesa, int argSaude, int argRaridade, char argAppearance)
    {
        Setup(argMap, argAtaque, argDefesa, argSaude, argRaridade, argAppearance);
    }

    // Sets private variables for this Item
    protected void Setup(Map argMap, int argAtaque, int argDefesa, int argSaude, int argRaridade, char argAppearance)
    {
        bool empty = false;
        while (!empty)
        {
            x = rng.Next(1, argMap.ReLengthX() - 1);
            y = rng.Next(1, argMap.ReLengthY() - 1);
            if (!argMap.CheckTile(y, x)) empty = true;
        }
        pickedUp = false;
        ataque = argAtaque;
        defesa = argDefesa;
        saude = argSaude;
        raridade = argRaridade;
        appearance = argAppearance;
     }
}
```

Now you can setup the base class with the calculated values:

```
class Armadura : Item
{
    public Armadura(Map argMap) 
    {
        int ataque = -1;
        int defesa = 2;
        int saude = 0;
        int raridade = ReRNG().Next(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(argMap.ReLengthY() * 0.02)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(argMap.ReLengthY() * 0.04)));
        char appearance = ' ';

        Setup(argMap, ataque, defesa, saude, raridade, appearance);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set ataque in the child constructor, as it will override what ataque is being set to in your base class.  The base constructor is called first, then the child constructor.

For this to work, you will need to make your private variables protected in the base class. This will make them private in the child class.